# Sort-Object produces different objects when using -Descending

Tags: powershell, sorting

Why does Sort-Object produce different objects when -Descending is used? The `NoteProperty` members are not the same.

Also, when writing to the console, the `Name` property does not appear unless `-Descending` is used. Why is that?

```
C:>Get-Type | Select-Object -Property BaseType,Name | gm

   TypeName: Selected.System.RuntimeType

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
BaseType    NoteProperty RuntimeType BaseType=System.Object
Name        NoteProperty string Name=Registry

C:>Get-Type | Select-Object -Property BaseType,Name | Sort-Object -Property BaseType,Name | gm

   TypeName: Selected.System.RuntimeType

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
BaseType    NoteProperty object BaseType=null
Name        NoteProperty string Name=_Activator

C:>Get-Type | Select-Object -Property BaseType,Name | Sort-Object -Property BaseType,Name -Descending | gm

   TypeName: Selected.System.RuntimeType

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
BaseType    NoteProperty RuntimeType BaseType=System.Xml.Xsl.XsltException
Name        NoteProperty string Name=XsltCompileException
```

My apologies for not including information about `Get-Type`. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Type-Get-exported-fee19cf7

Comment: Interesting, but you can you provide a [mcve]? `Get-Type` isn't a command on my machine, and it's difficult to tell what's going without knowing what you're actually sending into `Select-Object`.

Comment: Yep.  No idea what `Get-Type` is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a cmdlet that is natively part of PoSH. It's either something the OP wrote or got from another source. If from another source than the OP should reach out to that author to ask what is to be expected.

If you do this same things using a built-in cmdlet, say Get-Date, we see all members are the same.

```
Get-Date | 
Select-Object -Property BaseType,Name | 
Sort-Object -Property BaseType, Name  | 
Get-Member

  TypeName: Selected.System.DateTime

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
BaseType    NoteProperty object BaseType=null          
Name        NoteProperty object Name=null              



Get-Date | Select-Object -Property BaseType,Name | 
Sort-Object -Property BaseType, Name -Descending | 
Get-Member

   TypeName: Selected.System.DateTime

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
BaseType    NoteProperty object BaseType=null          
Name        NoteProperty object Name=null
```

So, would seem to point specifically to the implementation of this cmdlet the OP is looking for clarity on.

Comment: The source of `Get-Type` is in the question. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Type-Get-exported-fee19cf7 If needed, I can post the source of `Get-Type` in the question. It is not large.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that your `GetType` invocation results in an array starting with `$null` as it has a try-catch block providing an error value of `$null`. Then, should any parameters be passed to the `Get-Type`, that null would be filtered out, but you pass none, so null is still present in the output. Then, as the result is piped to `Select-Object`, only the first object in the pipe is parsed to check if all the columns are present to display, and should the null be the first object, it has no properties thus nothing gets displayed.

To fix, add the `| Where-Object {$_ -ne $null}` into the Get-Type.ps1 script right before `| Where-Object -FilterScript $WhereBlock` in the last significant line. This will filter out any nulls produced by previous try-catch block, and you will only get an array of objects that have values.

Comment: I tried changing the code as you suggest, but got the same result. I also tried `$_.BaseType -ne $null` and `$_.BaseType -ne ''` but all yielded the same result.

Comment: @lit Interesting then. Perhaps try grabbing the entire list of `Get-Type` and checkif all the objects in there have a name property. There should be some problems with the list, if sorting produces various results on the output.